# Backwards model selection, model average and model prediction. I'm lost

Tags: model-selection, glmm

I am trying to see whether two grouping variables and their interaction (let's call them B and C, where B has two levels and C has three levels) affect the behavior of an animal (described by A, a continuous variable). I also have three weather covariates which I use in my model, w1, w2 and w3, all continuous and I use the animal's individual identity as a random factor.

The full model looks like this: `A ~ B*C + B*C*w1 + B*C*w2 + B*C*w3 + (1|individual)`

I want to be able to use this model to predict how a future animal of the same species will behave under the same circumstances (which if I understand correctly means I am interested in model prediction).

Following authors of leading papers in my field, I used backwards model selection, starting with the full model. The results are that the best model includes both grouping variables (B and C), but not their interaction. This might be great, except that when I compare the AIC of this "best" model with the AIC of the same model, but with the interaction of B and C, the AIC difference is smaller than 1.

This is were I got lost because while the AIC difference between the two models is very small, the biological meaning of that difference is very big (i.e., if there is or isn't an interaction between the variables makes a big difference).
According to what I know and read, backwards model selection is not perfect, but is the best method if I want to get model predictions. But, is it really true in my case? Could a difference of <1 AIC between models be enough to remove the interaction and completely change the results?

This got me thinking about using model averaging, but then there is a problem with creating predictions using the averaged model, right?

Trying to summarize my questions:

1. Does a AIC difference <1 justify the removal of a model in backwards model selection, even when the difference between the two models is meaningful?
2. Can (and if so how) I use model averaging to get model predictions in this case?

Comment: This is not a good place for model selection and all of its problems with instability and distortion of statistical inference.   This is a place for careful model _specification_, then fitting the model and living with it (after perhaps running some basic diagnostics).

Comment: Thanks @FrankHarrell
But.. I am not sure I can do that, because it basically means that I "choose" the answer - whether the interaction has an effect, or only each of the grouping variables. I want to be able to statistically test this question, thus I am thinking about model avg. Any thoughts about that option?

Comment: You're not "choosing the answer" but instead would be specifying the grandest model that would be allowable and whose number of parameters to estimate would be sufficiently supported by the available sample size.  Model uncertainty renders other approaches problematic, i.e., if you select models in a way that reveals Y you will get (sometimes dramatic) underestimates of standard errors. Pre-specify a model and compute all desired contrasts off of that model.

Comment: Thanks again @FrankHarrell
Can you write some more about the last sentence? I am not sure I understand what it mean to "compute all desired contrasts off that model"

Comment: Sorry I meant to say to get predicted values and their confidence limits, for a variety of covariate settings.  Contrasts would be differences in predicted values, to estimate effects of e.g. varying one variable holding others constant.